Range of the function $\frac{x^4 + y^4 + z^4}{(x + y + z)^4}$ for $x,y,z>0$ such that $(x+y+z)^3 = 32xyz$
The question is: $x$, $y$, and $z$ are positive reals. If $(x+y+z)^3 = 32xyz$, then find the numerical range of $$f(x,y,z)=\frac{x^4 + y^4 + z^4}{(x + y + z)^4}.$$
Since all terms involved are positive, I realize the function is at least greater than $0$.
Since the denominator is greater than the numerator always (as they're positive), I believe the function is always less than $1$.
To find the proper limits, I tried to use the AM-GM inequality, but didn't understand how to proceed.
Can anyone please help me?

Hint: equation $(x+y+z)^3=32xyz$ is homogeneous. also, the degrees of polynomials on the numerator and denominator of $f$ are equal.

Can you elaborate on why the lower limit of the range is 0? I agree that $f(x,y,z) \geq 0$, but that doesn't mean that the minimum is 0. $\quad$ For example, even though $g(x) = x^2 + (x+2)^2 \geq 0 $, the range of $g(x)$ is not $[0, \infty)$.

@CalvinLin Oh yes it is my mistake,thank you for pointing it out, I will edit the question now
